# <c:if test='${empty Validated}'><jsp:forward page="/do/Index" /></c:if> not forwarding properly in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, jsp, struts-1

As part of a migration from Struts 1.x to Spring Boot I've been struggling with getting  to properly forward the info it should.

The original Struts version relied on a web.xml, and although I wanted to transition the project to a newer, entirely Java-based solution, its complexity made this a bit daunting and potentially unnecessary given the time constraints. I've also left the view parts in their original JSPs even though it's getting a bit long in the tooth.

-I have an initial banner.jsp page that comes up correctly once validation is passed.

-Clicking an Ok button on the banner.jsp page then tries to forward to an index.jsp page (where the above  code resides). The corresponding log produces (among other things):

…DispatcherServlet - "FORWARD" dispatch for POST "/Employees/do/Index", parameters={masked}
No mapping for POST /Employees/do/Index
Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404

("Employees" is the uri root off of which the various jsp pages reside)

-In the original Struts version after the index.jsp was hit and passed a populated template.jsp page displayed.

The 404 would seemingly just indicate a mapping problem, but as I've tried every uri variation I can think of I think the root of the problem is related to that jsp forward and Spring not understanding its "do/Index". In Struts this seems to be the construct by which parameter values are passed.

For a visual here's some of the related code:

banner.jsp

```
<form name="bannerForm" method="post" >
            <input type="hidden" name="accepted" value="yes" />
            <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
</form>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<c:if test='${empty Validated}'><jsp:forward page="/do/Index" /></c:if>
```

Any ideas what the problem might be or if there's an equivalent or work-around?

Comment: can you check is relative path correct and jsp files are in appropriate directory.Can you share view resolver in application.properties

Comment: My view resolver in application.properties is: spring.mvc.view.prefix: /
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp I've also tried variations, such as /WEB-INF/ and /WEB-INF/views -placing the pertinent jsps in each of these locations to test.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following configuration in application.properties

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

and your WEB-INF should be in src/main/webapp/ Folder.Complete path will be like src/master/vegcart/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/ (It is as per maven Project)

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the insight. It helps narrow the issue down. In doing some more digging I think I may have found the underlying problem. Maybe. I brought the original struts project into Eclipse to see what I might be missing and noticed I hadn't reworked the mapping in the struts-config.xml. I subsequently tried to convert the original forward and do/Index parts into a bean within a new class or as part of a config equivalent Spring would understand, but no luck (yet) configuring the right solution. If anyone had thoughts on Springifying the struts-config I'd welcome the help.